# Postgres Partial Index using foreign column

Tags: postgresql, partial-index

Consider the following table with a partial index:

```
CREATE TABLE triples(
  cardinality text NOT NULL,
  entity_id text NOT NULL,
  attribute text NOT NULL,
  value jsonb NOT NULL,
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX triples_ea ON triples(entity_id, attribute) INCLUDE(value) WHERE cardinality = 'one';
```

Here I've created a unique covering index on `entity_id` and `attribute`, based on the `cardinality` value.

But, **what if cardinality is in a different column?**

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE schema(
  id text PRIMARY KEY,
  cardinality text NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE triples(
  entity_id text,
  attribute text FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES schema(id),
  value jsonb
);
```

How could I write something along the lines of, if `cardinality` is in the referencing table?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX triples_ea ON triples(entity_id, attribute) INCLUDE(value) WHERE cardinality = 'one';
```

Comment: Not possible. An index can only contain data from **one** table.

Comment: Ah, thank you @a_horse_with_no_name ! If you like feel free to answer and resolve the question

Comment: You want a multi-table index. I've only seen true multi-table indexes in Oracle. Alternatively, you can index a materialized view; however, this is a whole different ball game, and you'll need decide how to manage stale data and refresh events.